# CSS without div's

Tags: css, grid

I'm currently teaching online and having a problem with HTML on the school's website.

When I enter a discussion board post, there's a "Source Code" option that lets me enter HTML so I can manually format my content rather than using the rich text option.  I'm trying to format my weekly supplemental material post using a CSS grid layout.  When I close the source code window, rather than saving my HTML as it was written, the LMS replaces every DIV tag with a P tag which the CSS doesn't seem to know what to do with.

Is there a way to do a CSS grid layout without using DIV tags?

Comment: Why did this get down voted?  It's a clear question with sufficient background information based on a real world problem.  I've worked in software development for over 20 years including taking helpdesk tickets so I know what an appropriate level of detail looks like.  This is the second time I have tried to ask a question only to have it down voted within the hour.

Comment: @Allen, did my answer help at all. It got down voted too.

Comment: I am not sure why it was down voted, but i would need to understand what specific CSS limitations exist for your "discussion board". What technology is it just so we can at least research.  CSS grid layout can be implemented via DIVs, tr/td, flexbox.  If your board strips box level elements and only supports inline tags, then you might be out of luck.

Comment: Probably the tool you're using doesn't support this use case. Maybe you should suggest that feature. You *could* use `<p>` instead of `<div>` (just replace `div` with `p` in your CSS code), but, unless it is a paragraph, you shouldn't.